# Is it really bad practice to add html markup for styling/skinning using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, frontend, right-to-left

I have a question, it's not the clearest but I wanted to see if anyone might have some ideas on it!

I'm working on an app, currently we only have one theme but in the future we will have many different ones, so this question's been on my mind a lot....

If you start off with clean HTML, and are just adding elements for styling purposes, is it ok to use jQuery to add extra elements? I think adding things this way makes it much easier to make adaptable layouts, and keeps your code cleaner and easier to understand, but I've always heard it's bad practice.

I use this system for quickly mocking up the files and it is so much faster than sorting through stacks of files and functions and classes to add this markup.

What are some examples of alternative systems for adding this sort of markup besides trudging through tons of code? Maybe with the example of making a static two column layout flexible, or  making a sliding doors button throughout the site...if anyone wants to take a stab at it you can also use forms as an example (something that for me has been tricky in terms of advanced styling)...and, heaven forbid, making it all switch to a right to left language layout!

Hopefully some font-end developers can sort of understand my question of wanting to keep my styling markup vs. functional markup separate. I appreciate any thoughts/suggestions/tutorials anyone can recommend!

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on JavaScript to display the content of your site will fail when a user comes to your site with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: If a user i s smart enough to disable javascript the user is also smart enough to understand the consequenses.

Comment: Is a discussion like this better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: ahhh hadn't seen that. Neat. Yeah this probably would have been better there, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much the way jQuery Mobile does it's formatting.
You need to put an attribute or two on an element (or nothing for basic elements) and then when your jQM page is about to be rendered jQM comes along and adds heaps of classes to the elements formatting it to suit.

Bad Practice - No!

Good Practice, probably especially if you intend your themes to be radically different

Should probably add that some minimal 'fixed' styling would help those who chose to turn off javascript.

Answer (score 1):

my understanding of your question: "is it OK to add things like:

```
<div class="topCap"></div>
```

with jQuery to keep my HTML clean?".

i don't know the standard, but i try to keep my html as static as possible.  if something might need a top cap, but the design doesn't call for it -- it's in my html anyways.

i do this to keep client-side load time down.  i don't mind writing/delivering additional HTML, but I hate when my browser has to make new elements when it loads.

Answer (score 1):

First of all adding items dynamically is fine, for example:

```
var item = $(document.createElement('div'));
```

I'm working on a template based app. The way i do it is that i create an html template and then i load it into a main container using ajax. That way i can have pages lying as templates in an HTML folder and drag them into the "scene" when needed.

Edit: You should be aware that the markup probably wont be visible for search engines to index.

Comment: Do you use it for mostly larger or smaller components? I use some html templates on my project for larger components, it used to contain smaller ones but I ended up needing to do some php translations and had to move them out of it (although I could have made it php instead of html), but so far it's working well for main layout stuff. I keep searching for some super organized system, right now I have markup being generated in 10 different files for each page, and it's making me a bit crazy...I guess that's just part of moving to apps though...

Comment: 10 files sounds a bit crazy. If you need a dynamic button then add it with jquery/javascript. If you need an entire template then have a static html page and pull that one in.

Answer (score 1):

I've written apps that consume JSON and build 90% of the UI in JavaScript. Because this is an APPLICATION and not a PAGE, a lot of what we do for SEO and semantic HTML doesn't really apply. I'd never expect Google to index this page.

Regardless, I try to keep the mark-up to a minimum to allow the structure and styling to work.

There is also the issue of **progressive enhancement**: starting off with basic HTML, then using JS to add functionality. Is this a bad practice -- no, not really.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Seems to still be what you are looking for. When you give elements classes and ID's, name those classes and ID's after the function you want the content to convey. For example, Let's say in your current layout you want a bright red alert area for error messages: Instead of naming that class="red", try naming it class="alert". That way if you decide to re-skin the whole site you can simply make a new css stylesheet and change your entire layout without ever having to edit HTML or Javascript. Another advantage to this is that using classes and ID's appropriately will make any interaction you have to perform using JQuery much easier in the future.

Comment: Theoretically that should work, I think we're getting much closer to that with CSS3, but a lot of the time I still find myself needing to add extra markup...just think of adding a sticky footer!